# MvvmCross V3 + Nuget - how to resolve dll not found issue?

Tags: nuget, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I am attempting to work through the N+1 TipCalc tutorial & get the following error when trying to compile the core project:

```
Error   1   Metadata file '1\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore.3.0.4\lib\portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp71\Cirrious.CrossCore.dll' could not be found   C:\Source.CS\trunk\Learning\Mono\TipCalc1\TipCalc.N=1\TipCalc.Core\CSC  TipCalc.Core
Error   2   Metadata file '1\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack.3.0.4\lib\portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp71\Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll' could not be found C:\Source.CS\trunk\Learning\Mono\TipCalc1\TipCalc.N=1\TipCalc.Core\CSC  TipCalc.Core
Error   3   Metadata file '1\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore.3.0.4\lib\portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp71\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization.dll' could not be found  C:\Source.CS\trunk\Learning\Mono\TipCalc1\TipCalc.N=1\TipCalc.Core\CSC  TipCalc.Core
```

NuGet 2.5 RC was installed from here https://nuget.codeplex.com/
Profile104 xml files created as per instructions & have been used for a few weeks with V3 prior to attempting to use NuGet for the MvvmCross components.
Pre NuGet TipCalc tutorial was accomplished without problems.

Downloading the complete project from GitHub also compiles without issues.
I haven't been able to see any difference between the packages.config file in the downloaded project and the project being created from scratch.
The profile of the core project is also the same in each case.
The dll's are at the location indicated.

There were no issues with using NuGet to download the package, only when attempting to compile the project.

Any suggestions as to what I have missed?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My **guess** is that the problem is in your path

The path seems to be `C:\Source.CS\trunk\Learning\Mono\TipCalc1\TipCalc.N=1\TipCalc.Core\CSC`

And the message is that `'1\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore.3.0.4\lib\portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp71\Cirrious.CrossCore.dll' could not be found`

So maybe try using a path without an `=`?

Comment: Guess correct... thanks.

Never even occured to me that the = would cause a problem.